# Using Tikz to put text next to shapes

Tags: tikz-pgf

Hi i'm fairly new to Latex. Would anyone know how to get this using Tikz? Cheers. 
[image]

Comment: Welcome to TeX. SX! This seems quite easy; have you read the tutorials in the TikZ Manual? Please post the code you tried and  we will help you...

Answer (score 5):

You can use e.g.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{labeled square/.cd,a/.initial=pi*1em,b/.initial=2pt,}
\newcommand{\LabeledSquare}[5][]{\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline={(W.base)},   
    thick,nodes={inner sep=0pt,text height=0.8em,text depth=0.25ex},#1]
 \draw (0,0) -- node[pos=0.5,left=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled square/b}](W) {$#2$} ++ (0,-\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled square/a})
 -- node[pos=0.5,below=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled square/b}] {$#3$} ++ (\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled square/a},0)
 -- node[pos=0.5,right=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled square/b}] {$#4$} ++ (0,\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled square/a})
 -- node[pos=0.5,above=\pgfkeysvalueof{/tikz/labeled square/b}] {$#5$} cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}}
\begin{document}
\[
 \LabeledSquare{T_3}{T_2}{T_1}{T_0}
 =
 \LabeledSquare{0}{0}{0}{T_0}
 +
 \LabeledSquare{0}{0}{T_1}{0}
 +
 \LabeledSquare{0}{T_2}{0}{0}
 +
 \LabeledSquare{T_3}{0}{0}{0}
\] 
\tikzset{labeled square/a=4em}
\[
 \LabeledSquare{T_3}{T_2}{T_1}{T_0}
 =
 \LabeledSquare[red]{0}{0}{0}{T_0}
 +
 \LabeledSquare[orange]{0}{0}{T_1}{0}
 +
 \LabeledSquare[blue]{0}{T_2}{0}{0}
 +
 \LabeledSquare[cyan]{T_3}{0}{0}{0}
\] 
\end{document}
```

[image]

To make sure that the shape blends nicely into the equation, we use the `baseline` of the left edge label to set the baseline of the `tikzpicture`. In order to avoid that the opposite edge label is off, we set some (empirical) values for the `text height` and `text depth`. As you can see, you can change all these parameters either with `\tikzset` or by using the optional argument, or both.

Comment: OMG, thank you so much. This is a life saver. Thanks a million